# resize file string php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a piece of code that I use to store image to the database, sometimes it can be a pdf as well.

I take the string and store it directly to the database.  I want to change the file size and then store it to the database so I don't store file size that are bigger than 1MB.

I want to resize it just before storing.

Here is the peice of code

```
$filename =     'file'.$i;

                    $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','_',strtolower($_FILES[$filename]['name']));
                    $tmpName        = $_FILES[$filename]['tmp_name'];
                    $ImageSize      = $_FILES[$filename]['size'];                   
                    $ImageType      = $_FILES[$filename]['type']; //"image/png", image/jpeg etc.

                    $ImageExt       = substr($ImageName, strrpos($ImageName, '.'));
                    $ImageExt       = str_replace('.','',$ImageExt);
                    $ImageName      = preg_replace("/\.[^.\s]{3,4}$/", "", $ImageName);
                    $ImageName      = $ImageName.'.'.$ImageExt;

                    $fp             = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
                    $image          = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
                    fclose($fp);
```

I am not sure how I can resize it.

Comment: Are you trying to check the file size? If so, just use [`filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php).

Comment: I know the file size, I want to make the file size smaller on the fly. Like reduce compress it somehow...and store to db.

Comment: ..and what if the file isn't compressible?  You can't just "change" the file size..

Comment: @Devon but I convert the file to string, so won't it be possible to compress that?

Comment: @Script47 I tried that one, the image file is unreadable then.

Comment: *"sometimes it can be a pdf"* ... well that'll throw a spanner in the works if you want to automatically optimise the image with something like GD Library.

Comment: @CD001 I don't have storing file to db problem on a local computer but when I put it to heroku my db doesnt accept more than 1 mb, hence I asked this problem here, and contacting heroku dnt work, looks like bots work there.

Comment: Why don't you just store the file on the server and store the reference in the db?

Comment: Yes, follow @Script47 s advice; never store files in a database if you can avoid it -- large blobs slow down db-maintenance tasks (backups, ...)